# Regex: Select only the dots that are followed by words that start with a lowercase letter

Tags: notepad++, regex, sublime-text-3

I want to use regex as to select only the dots that are followed by words that start with a lowercase letter.

Example:

1: My cat is here. and I don't know where is the dog.

2: My cat is here. And I don't know where is the dog.

The output should be the 1 line. And regex must find `. a` (from `. and I don't know`)

My regex seems almost good, but also selects the second line, `. A` (this did not have to be selected)

FIND: `\. [a-z]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**With Sublime Text**

- Find what: `\. \p{L}`

OR

- Find what:`\. [a-z]`
- Enable case sensitive

**With Notepad++**

- Find what: `\. [a-z]`
- Match case: enable

Comment: thanks, it works